# Where can I find this song from The World is Still Beautiful?

Tags: music, the-world-is-still-beautiful

I'm searching for song from episode 12 of the anime adaptation of The World is Still Beautiful (それでも世界は美しい). I know both title and vocalist, but can't find it anywhere. It's called "Ame Okuri no Uta" （雨おくりの歌）　by Chisa Yokoyama　（横山智佐）.

It is shown in the list of insert songs in the credit roll of episode 12:

[image: Episode 12 - Credit roll]

Comment: Do you mean "Ame furashi no uta"? If so, that song can be found on the official soundtrack (track #15), which is available on Amazon Japan: http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AF%E7%BE%8E%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E9%9F%B3%E6%A5%BD%EF%BC%9A%E5%B1%B1%E4%B8%8B%E5%BA%B7%E4%BB%8B/dp/B00K8KTR5G/. I can't seem to find anything about a song called "Ame okuri no uta", though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this song isn't included in OST(i listened to all songs in it)

Comment: An instrumental version of 雨おくりの歌 is going to be included in an extra CD that comes with the [BD](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00L4G71EM)/[DVD](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00L4G96T0) box to be released on September 24 ([source](https://twitter.com/soreseka_anime/status/484282668582850561)), though I have no idea about releases outside Japan. As for the on-vocal version, no information has been released.

Comment: For everything I've looked up, I cannot find it either. Perhaps it wasn't posted on the internet... or maybe it simply wasn't meant to be for anyone else. They didn't even have it in the official album.

Comment: @senshin [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15853) lists it but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_is_Still_Beautiful#Anime) or [Anime Lyrics](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/soredemosekai) don't, however the last 2 list Amefurashi no Uta ~Beautiful Rain~ while Anime New Network doesn't while all 3 are consistent with the OP and ED